Gfci switch and receptacle for bathroom light

When I have this wired in the main power goes in the line. The switch goes in to the wire on the back of outlet. Both neutral wires are hooked in to the line also. This is the only way the switch will turn on the light. The outlet doesn’t work at all, with the switch on or off.

1 - Where do the cables come from/go to? Presumably one is power, but is the other to a light or a switch or a receptacle? 2 - What is the device here? Can only see the wires going in the back, so not clear whether this is a plain receptacle or a GFCI/receptacle or something else.

Is there a black jumper wire going from the black side screw to the white side back insert? Sounds wrong if so.

It is a gfci switch and outlet. One yellow wire is power and the other is to the light. One black wire is wired to the light and the other is connected to the receptacle for the line. Both neutral wires are connected to the line

If it is a combined GFCI receptacle+switch, I would expect 6 connections can be made: Line live + neutral, switched load live + neutral, unswitched load live + neutral. Can you update your question with a picture of the back of the device, showing the markings there, and can you add as much information as you have about the model?

It is an Eaton TRSGFS15 gfci receptacle with switch. I ended up installing it so I could finish the job and when I figure it out I’d take the outlet back out. So I can’t pull it out just now.
